# Is there a difference between "poco" and "un poco"?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos

In English, there's a subtle but definite difference between *few* and *a few*:

> A few men went to the party. (*Some people went*)
>
> Few men went to the party. (*Nobody or almost nobody went*)

Does this difference also exist between the **un poco** and **poco** of Spanish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is the same difference and then a bit more.

We could translate your examples into Spanish as follows:

> A few men went to the party --> A la fiesta fueron unos pocos hombres.
>
> Few men went to the party --> A la fiesta fueron pocos hombres.

In the first example we'd probably say *algunos hombres*, but *unos pocos hombres* is usable, too. The meaning of these sentences are basically the same as in English.

Then, we also have a difference between *poco* and *un poco*. In this case, *poco* works as an adverb and may be translated as *little* in English, though this translation does not always work too well.

For instance:

> Pon un poco de azúcar sobre la tarta --> Put a little sugar over the cake
>
> Pon poco azúcar sobre la tarta --> Don't put much sugar over the cake

The general meaning is similar, but *un poco* can be considered opposed to *nothing*, while *poco* is opposed to *a lot*. In both cases it is an amount between nothing and a lot, but the gist is different.

Comment: You've beaten me by just 8 seconds! :-)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo I did not mean it to become a race, but eat dust! :P

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I think that subtle difference is also present in Spanish. I think the best example is this:

> Durmió poco. *(He didn't sleep enough.)*
>
> Durmió un poco. *(He at least slept some time.)*

You can see this difference even in the DRAE, in the definition of *[poco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TTT0e1l)*:

> POCO: En número, cantidad o intensidad escasos respecto de lo regular, ordinario o preciso.
>
> UN POCO: Una cantidad pequeña.

The difference is that if you say just *poco*, you're implying you have a scale and that the amount you are measuring didn't reach a expected level (*escasos **respecto de lo regular***). If you say *un poco* you don't have that scale, you're just implying a small amout.