# ¿Puede "un poco" significar "mucho"?

Tags: gramática, modismos, adjetivos

Ya se ha hecho antes la pregunta acerca de la diferencia entre ["poco" y "un poco"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17945/is-there-a-difference-between-poco-and-un-poco).
Las respuestas allí son claras y concuerdo con ellas.

Mi problema es que en determinados usos, le doy a "un poco" un significado opuesto. Por ejemplo, para mí esta frase:

> Hay un poco de periodistas en la calle.

puede significar que hay *muchos* periodistas en la calle. Algunas veces había pensado en eso y en lo particular que era esa palabra, por poder significar cosas tan distintas. Sin embargo, no fue hasta hoy que se me ocurrió que es probable que siempre haya usado esa forma de manera equivocada. En la RAE no encuentro indicio del uso que le he dado. ¿En algun contexto/región puede "un poco" significar mucho? ¿O estoy solo con mi error?

Comment: Bueno, yo tengo otro problema con "un poco de periodistas."  Para mí, "un poco" es para cosas que no se cuentan, como el agua.  No puedo imaginar que esta frase se diga así.  Creo que más bien se diría, "Hay unos cuantos periodistas."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El uso que comentas de *un poco* parece que es propio de algunos países de Hispanoamérica, tal y como recoge [el párrafo 20.2q](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=pngCURZhTAbwQgAp) de la *Nueva gramática española* de la RAE:

> En el español popular de Venezuela y Colombia, así como en el de Costa Rica y otras partes de Centroamérica, se usa *un poco* en construcciones pseudopartitivas no concordadas, con el sentido de *muchos(s)*, como en *Se demoró un poco de días* ('Se demoró muchos días'); *Había un poco de niños* ('Había muchos niños'), o en *un poco de problemas* ('muchos problemas') [...]. Esta construcción no ha pasado a los registros formales.

Por tanto, parece que la frase que mencionas sí es usada en tu región (veo que eres precisamente de Colombia) y está documentada, como ves. En todo caso, se indica que es un coloquialismo. Se puede usar en entornos no formales, pero no se recomienda si vas a usar un tono más formal.

Siempre es curioso ver cómo una misma idea se expresa de forma diferente según el país e incluso la región. A mí me habría salido de forma natural esa misma expresión así:

> ¡Anda que no hay periodistas en la calle!

El uso de la ironía es muy común en el lenguaje, por ejemplo con [expresiones como](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wMzFXvhRiwOtzsRs):

> ¡Contenta me tienes!
>   ¡Bien empezamos!

que en realidad expresan justo lo contrario de lo que su sentido literal dice.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Por si a alguien más, como a mí, le era desconocido el término "pseudopartitiva", recomiendo este enlace: https://juditdediego.es/2015/11/05/construcciones-partitivas-gramatica-espanol-concordancia-sujeto-verbo/.

Comment: solo para complementar a @Charlie, el diccionario de americanismos te confirma el significado de [poco](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=poco) en varios países

Answer (score 0):

En España, «un poco» puede significar «muy», «bastante», «demasiado».

Hoy no voy a salir: estoy un poco cansado = estoy bastante cansado = estoy muy cansado = estoy demasiado cansado.

Lo mismo ocurre con «algo» con el sentido de «un poco»:

Este ejercicio es algo difícil para un niño tan pequeño (= muy difícil = bastante difícil = demasiado difícil).

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, pedruchini, fíjate que el uso de "un poco" que mencionas se parece más al referido en la [pregunta enlazada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17945/12637) por el propio Mauricio en su pregunta, que básicamente se refiere a la diferencia entre decir "vinieron pocos" o "vinieron unos pocos". En España diríamos "hay unos pocos periodistas" pero en Colombia se dice "hay un poco de periodistas", y Mauricio quería saber si ese uso de "un poco de" como "muchos" es correcto o no.