# Dos millones de personas están... ¿expuestas o expuestos? Un millón de personas... ¿tendrá o tendrán?

Tags: género, concordancia-gramatical, número-gramatical

Me ha surgido la duda que explico a continuación sobre cómo se tiene que hacer la concordancia de género en frases con un predicado nominal en las cuales el sujeto contiene la expresión "millones de personas". El problema es que "millones" es masculino y "personas" es femenino.

Es este [libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=ptMbO0Uk_doC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=%22Dos+millones+de+personas+est%C3%A1n%22&source=bl&ots=WAgmJqRoYN&sig=ACfU3U34sf5O8IJdDLuV_6ZzpsXafyPkbA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLgv78ho7pAhUK8hoKHapGCko4ChDoATAAegQIARAB#v=onepage&q=%22Dos%20millones%20de%20personas%20est%C3%A1n%22&f=false) he encontrado un ejemplo:

> Dos millones de personas están expuestas a sufrir sus efectos.

¿Podría ser como sigue, concordando "expuestos" con "millones"?

> Dos millones de personas están expuestos a sufrir sus efectos.

¿Se admiten las dos versiones?

Intentando resolver mi duda, he encontrado este [artículo en el sitio web de consultas lingüísticas de la RAE](https://www.rae.es/consultas/la-mayoria-de-los-manifestantes-el-resto-de-los-alumnos-la-mitad-de-los-presentes-etc). Si he entendido bien cómo aplicar lo que expone al caso que planteo, la única opción correcta en este caso es

> Dos millones de personas están expuestas a sufrir sus efectos

porque "expuestas a sufrir sus efectos" es un  predicativo que debe concordar con "personas" y no con "millones". ¿Es así?

Así mismo, debemos decir

> Dos millones de personas son analfabetas

concordando "analfabetas" con "personas" y no con "millones".

Puestos a clarificar este tema, también estaría bien entender cómo se tiene que hacer la concordancia entre el verbo y un sujeto que contenga la expresión "un millón de" en el caso de un predicado verbal.

En el ejemplo siguiente creo que, si he sabido aplicar bien lo que he leído en el artículo de la RAE que he mencionado antes, tenemos dos opciones válidas, concordando el verbo con "un millón" (singular) o con "personas" (plural):

> Un millón de personas tendrá que desplazarse

o bien

> Un millón de personas tendrán que desplazarse.

¿Lo he entendido todo bien o se me ha escapado algo?

Mi interesa especialmente saber si la opción "Un millón de personas tendrá...", con el verbo en singular, es realmente correcta, aunque quizás no sea la más usual.  Lo que me hace dudar en este caso es que "un millón" realmente es un número mayor que uno (como lo es, por ejemplo, "novecientas mil" o "cinco"): no sé si esto hace que sea en cierto modo diferente de expresiones como "una treintena" o "un centenar".<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1. Tratando de resolver esta duda, he intentado buscar información sobre "un millón", pero no he encontrado nada útil. En cambio, curiosamente, sí que hemos (digo "hemos" porque me han ayudado en Italian.SE) información sobre "un milione" en italiano, cosa que me ha servido para aclarar una duda parecida en esa lengua. Intento explicar lo que hemos encontrado en comentarios a esta pregunta, por si sirve para dar ideas sobre qué tipo de cosas buscar a los interesados en dar una respuesta.</sup>

Comment: Creo que has entendido bien. Habría que agregar que con predicado verbal es más habitual el plural que el singular.

Comment: @Gustavson No había caído en eso, que es lo que transforma la pregunta en verdaderamente interesante.

Comment: las recompensas (_bounty_) suelen ayudar a estos menesteres :D

Comment: He reportado mi respuesta por haber sido expandida sin mi autorización. La pregunta original era, antes de su edición al día siguiente de mi respuesta. "Mi interesa especialmente saber si la opción "Un millón de personas tendrá...", con el verbo en singular, es realmente correcta, aunque quizás no sea la más usual." La respuesta atendía a dicha pregunta. La pregunta fue expandida, lo cual crea una situación de metas móbiles que es intolerable.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming': No me parece mala idea, pero se me ocurre que primero podría intentar explicar más o menos lo que he encontrado en italiano para dar ideas sobre qué buscar. Estoy pensando cómo hacerlo.

Comment: @Ricardo: Lo único que añadí a la pregunta después de tu respuesta es la última frase: no cambia la pregunta, es únicamente una aclaración de qué es exactamente lo que me genera mi duda. Y me sabe mal que hayas eliminado tu respuesta: me parecía un buen inicio de respuesta, únicamente le faltaba alguna cosa para completarla.

Comment: El libro *Italiano* de Luca Serianni explica que "milione" y "bilione" non son propiamente numerales cardinales como, por ejemplo, cinco o novecientas mil. Intento traducir lo que dice: "*Milione*, *bilione*, *milardo*, etc. [...] no son cardinales propiamente dichos, sino simples sustantivos con su regular plural que, para indicar una cantidad determinada, tienen que estar necesariamente precedidos de un cardinal («*un* milione di dollari», «*duecentoventisei* miliardi di disavanzo»)".

Comment: Hemos encontrado ejemplos de frases con sujeto "un milione di" y el verbo en singular: "un milione di persone è dove in teoria non potrebbe essere" (diario *la Repubblica*), "Un milione di persone è pronto ad invadere l'Area 51" (informazione.it), "Oltre un milione di ettari nella peni­sola è incolto" (Carducci), "più di un milione di persone è sceso in piazza" (diario *Stylo24*). Estos son ejemplos de frases con predicado verbal. Por ejemplo, la traducción literal del primero sería: "un millón de personas está donde en teoría no podría estar".

Comment: Si alguien quiere escribir una respuesta, se sienta libre de utilizar esto si quiere. Respecto a la primera parte de la pregunta, la que hace referencia a un predicado nominal, me he autoconvencido de que lo que he interpretado con ayuda del artículo de la RAE es lo correcto. A parte de leer el contenido del link que había en la respuesta (que a mi pesar ha desaparecido), que me ha venido muy bien, he hecho mis razonamientos para intentar entender la razón. La idea es que "expuestas" califica a "personas" y no a "millones", por eso debe concordar con "personas". (Sigue)

Comment: (Cont.) Por ejemplo, podemos decir "Un millón de personas en esta región son analfabetas". Está claro que "analfabetas" califica a "personas" y, por eso, concuerda con "personas" (y también el verbo en plural): los "millones" no pueden ser o no ser analfabetos. Diferente sería si hicieramos una frase como, por ejemplo, "El grupo de turistas japonesas era muy nutrido". En esta oración, "nutrido" califica a "grupo" y no a "turistas japonesas": por eso debe concordar con "grupo", es decir, estar en masculino singular (igual que el verbo "era").

Comment: También podríamos decir "Dos grupos de turistas japonesas eran muy nutridos, mientras que el resto se había reducido a cuatro gatos".

Comment: Y, forzando quizás un poco el lenguaje, se me ocurre que, en una situación en la que una determinada moneda ha dejado de tener validez o ha sufrido una gran devaluación, quizás tendría sentido decir algo como "tengo un millón de billetes en la caja fuerte, pero es un millón inútil" (una frase con la estructura "un millón de billetes es inútil" parece tener algún sentido).

Comment: Lo que he escrito en los comentarios anteriores son películas que yo me he hecho y que quizás no hagan falta. Puede que se trate simplemente de aplicar la regla gramatical "pero si el verbo lleva un atributo o un complemento predicativo (es decir, un elemento que, formando parte del predicado, atribuye cualidades o estados a la entidad designada por el sujeto), solo es normal poner el verbo en plural, pues el atributo o el predicativo deben concordar asimismo en plural con el sustantivo plural al que se refieren". Pero el "solo es normal" me hace pensar que existe alguna excepción a esta regla

Answer (score 2):

No estoy de acuerdo con la mayoría de las respuestas que he visto a esta pregunta.

Siguiendo el razonamiento de la propia RAE:

https://mobile.twitter.com/raeinforma/status/1249956627135987712?lang=es

> #RAEconsultas La palabra «millón» no es un determinante, sino un sustantivo (masculino plural); al ser este sustantivo el núcleo del sintagma nominal «millones de personas», el artículo tiene que concordar con él en género y número: «los 10 millones de mascarillas».

El núcleo del sintagma nominal es el millón en "un millón", "dos millones", etc. (que queda calificado con "de personas") y por tanto hay que hacerlo coincidir con el verbo:

> Un millón de personas vino a la manifestación.

La pregunta es "¿de qué es el millón?". De la misma forma se califican otras cosas: una tarta de queso, un trío de payasos...

Answer (score 1):

Haciendo un análisis sintáctico sobre la oración:

**"Dos millones de personas están expuestas a sufrir sus efectos."**

Podemos ver que:

- "Dos millones de": es un adjetivo cardinal que cuantifica al sustantivo.
- "personas": es el sustantivo.
- "están": es el verbo, acción sobre el sustantivo; en este caso sobre las ***personas***.
- "expuestas a sufrir sus efectos.": predicado.

Cualquier consideración a tenerse en cuenta en el predicado debería aplicarse sobre sustantivo, teniéndose en cuenta su genero y número. Por lo tanto, el género al que debes hacer referencia en el predicado es al del sustantivo y no al del adjetivo.

La cardinalidad del adjetivo afecta al número del sustantivo. Si la cantidad es de valor uno, el sustantivo es singular; cualquier número distinto de uno indica que el sustantivo es plural.

La palabra "millón" o "millones" podría usado como sustantivo (no como adjetivo) en otro contexto, como ser: "El millón es un gran número.", o bien, en la oración "Dos millones superan al número anterior". En estos casos, la palabra millón se se utiliza como sustantivo y no como adjetivo.

En esta precisa oración: "Dos millones de personas están expuestas a sufrir sus efectos.", como así también en el caso de "Un millón de personas están expuestas a sufrir sus efectos."

Si tenemos en cuenta esto, decir que las personas están "expuestas" (por su género) y las personas "tendrán" (por su número) son respuestas correctas a tus preguntas.

De cualquier manera, ésto ha sido sólo mi modesto análisis.

En búsqueda de la verdad sobre usos y costumbres, según lo que he investigado http://iesbinef.educa.aragon.es/lengua/sintaxis/sintaxisweb/teoria.htm#a42 sobre **Sintagma nominal o grupo nominal**, expresa que:

- Cuando el núcleo del sujeto es un sustantivo colectivo seguido por un complemento cuyo término está en plural, el verbo podrá concordar indistintamente ya en singular con el colectivo núcleo, ya en plural con el término del complemento.

  - Un grupo de jóvenes se subió a la valla.
  - Un grupo de jóvenes se subieron a la valla.

Por lo que a fin de cuentas puedes usar de forma indistinta uno u otro modo según tu parecer.

Saludos!

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias por tu contribución. Pero también "millón" es un sustantivo. Y la pregunta es un poco más amplia.

Comment: De [este blog](http://grupolacolina.blogspot.com/2015/02/las-monedas-de-monedero-jean-maninat-en.html?m=1): «[...] una vez contado el millón de votos que obtuvieron, [...]». Nos explican que el millón de votos ha sido contado. La concordancia del verbo con el sujeto "el millón de votos" se ha hecho al singular y parece natural (también en la frase original "contado" concuerda con "millón" y no con "votos").

Comment: En mi contribución intento explicar bajo qué reglas gramaticales se suscribe la correcta forma de expresarse ante los interrogantes de si es correcto expresarlo de una forma u otra. La verdad es que se han de encontrar en diversas fuentes expresado de muy variadas formas, pero no por ello, éstas, estén cumpliendo las formas de construcción  gramatical del español.

Comment: De verdad, como dices en tu primer comentario, puedes encontrar "millón" como sustantivo, pero no justamente en esta oración. Se convierte en sustantivo cuando millón se transforma en el sujeto del predicado, como ser en la oración "El millón es un número que inicia con uno seguido se seis ceros.", pero en el caso de estar aplicado sobre un sustantivo, su función cambia al de adjetivo.

Comment: Cuando hablamos de uno (o más) millones de personas, lo que hacemos es cuantificar el sustantivo concreto de la oración, que en este caso es personas, ya que no dá lo mismo si hablamos de millón de personas, caballos o monos. El sustantivo es "personas", siendo el adjetivo "millón de", el que dá idea de la magnitud de estas, pero bien podría no estar en la oración y la misma tendría igual sentido semántico.

Comment: Bien podemos decir "un millón de personas están expuestas a sufrir sus efectos", o "dos millones de personas están expuestas a sufrir sus efectos", como así también podemos decir "las personas están expuestas a sufrir sus efectos" (sin indicar magnitud), ya que las oraciones tiene sentido por si mismas; no es el caso de decir "Un millón está expuesto a sufrir sus efectos" ya que por si mismo carece de contexto y requiere de una explicación previa para que la expresión sea correcta semánticamente.

Comment: "Un millón está expuesto a sufrir sus efectos", es correcto semánticamente, por lo tanto, si la expresión está compuesta por dos o mas oraciones que explican el sentido, convirtiendo en la presente oración la palabra "millón" en el sujeto de la misma, y no, como está expresado en el enunciado de ésta pregunta: "Dos millones de personas están… ¿expuestas o expuestos? Un millón de personas… ¿tendrá o tendrán?", que claramente se utiliza como adjetivo cardinal. La cantidad de millones se utiliza para dar idea de magnitud en la misma, pero el sustantivo, es sin lugar a dudas, la palabra personas.

Comment: No estoy del todo segura de estar entendiendo del todo bien lo que estás diciendo en tus comentarios, pero mira los míos a la pregunta en los que explico lo que hemos encontrado para el italiano (y otras cosas que he razonado yo). Serianni es un lingüista de gran reputación.

Comment: De acuerdo, es para el italiano y no para el español, pero mi impresión ahora mismo es que también es válido para el español. La única diferencia es que, por mi experiencia y por lo que he leído, la concordancia *ad sensum* la hacemos con más frecuencia en español que en italiano (he encontrado bastantes italianos que piensan que se debe evitar, mientras que los artículos de la RAE dicen que es más frecuente). Por otro lado, creo que deberías completar tu publicación para dar respuesta a todo lo que pido.

Comment: No debería usarse el genero y numero del adjetivo, sino del sustantivo, para expresarlo del modo correcto, mas allá de modismos, costumbres o faltas que se pudieran utilizar en blogs, post, papers o cualquier publicación que no sigan reglas gramaticales del español. Es mi humilde aporte. Ha sido un gusto de cualquier manera haber contribuído.

Comment: Perfecto, intentaré ampliar mi publicación para contemplar mi explicación. Realmente mi intención es la de contribuir a ésta comunidad con lo que puedo aportar, y en el caso de estár equivocado, aprender sobre nuevas reglas para expresarlo mejor.

Comment: (Mis disculpas por la discusión generada, nuevamente mi intención es la de construir).

Answer (score 0):

No hablo bien español, pero voy a tratar de explicar mi respuesta. Cuando se tiene una oración como "Un millón de personas hacen/hace algo," hay dos respuestas. Se puede decir cualquier verbo porque el sujeto puede ser "las personas" o "un millón." Pero es mejor decir "hace" porque el sujeto de la oración realmente es un millón. Decir que el verbo debe ser "hacen" es una concordancia ad sensum (https://www.yourdictionary.com/constructio-ad-sensum, http://udep.edu.pe/castellanoactual/concordancia-ad-sensum/) y no es gramatical.

Por el otro lado, con una descripción (por ejemplo, "La mayoría de sus hijos eran altos"), el adjetivo se refiere a los hijos. Aunque el sujeto de la oración puede ser "la mayoría" o "los hijos," el adjetivo describe los hijos y por eso tiene que ser altos, no alta.

La última pregunta: "Un millón de personas" es correcto. https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vcodigo=1530 tiene un discurso interestante que dice que "un millon de personas" es un sujeto singular.

Dicho esto, creo que Usted ha entendido bien.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Nota que el artículo de la RAE que citado en la pregunta afirma que la concordancia *ad sensum* es más habitual.

Comment: La última pregunta no es si "un millón de personas" es o no correcto. Es si, con este sujeto y un predicado verbal, el verbo se puede conjugar en singular. Y surge por la duda sobre si "millón" es o no un numeral como "novecientas mil" o se comporta más bien como un sustantivo que indica una colectividad, como "centenar".

Comment: Según la información que he encontrado en italiano (mira mis comentarios a la pregunta), yo apuesto por la segunda opción. El problema es que la información la he encontrado para "milione", aunque tengo la sensación que probablemente también es válida para "millón".

Comment: Me gusta la explicación que has hecho sobre que el adjetivo en tu ejemplo describe a los hijos y por eso tiene que ser "altos", no "alta". Pero a continuación, por completitud, añadiría algo como «Por la misma razón, hay que decir "Dos millones de personas están expuestas a sufrir sus efectos" y no "Dos millones de personas están expuestos a sufrir sus efectos".»

Comment: Y si quieres añadir alguno de los ejemplos que he puesto yo en mis comentarios a la pregunta, adelante. Los puedes copiar sin ningún problema.

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco en la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22513/puede-un-poco-significar-mucho), en un comentario del op se hacía mención a la explicación de [construcciones partitivas](https://juditdediego.es/2015/11/05/construcciones-partitivas-gramatica-espanol-concordancia-sujeto-verbo/). Si bien hace más referencia al número que al género, creo que puede aplicar de la misma forma. Veamos lo que dice el artículo:

> Las construcciones partitivas y pseudopartitivas responden a la posibilidad de cuantificar prácticamente toda referencia real; es decir, expresan la parte de un todo que hace de sujeto en una oración
>   *La mayoría de los clientes paga sin demora.*
>   En estos casos, el sujeto está formado por un sintagma o grupo nominal. Este, como es evidente, se llama así porque su núcleo —o palabra eje— es un sustantivo o nombre en número singular, pero con un significado de colectividad. Este sustantivo va acompañado de un cuantificador y lo sigue un complemento preposicional, introducido siempre por de.(...)
>   ¿Qué problema hay en el uso de estas construcciones? Si, por norma general, al sujeto en singular (El cliente) le corresponde, por concordancia, un verbo en singular (paga muy bien), en las construcciones partitivas esto no queda tan claro. En ellas, el hablante —o el escribiente— no concuerda bien el sujeto y el verbo al encontrarse con una estructura en que el primer término está en singular y el segundo, en plural.

Ahora, en el caso que traes (Dos millones de personas) debemos saber cuál es el núcleo. Como vimos, viene precedido del *de*, así que nuestro núcleo es el término *personas* y debería recibir la concordancia. Para confirmarlo, veamos lo que nos sugieren:

> Por lo general, se acepta una concordancia doble; esto es, la alternancia entre la concordancia en singular o en plural, siendo ambas opciones correctas (...) Ya hemos dicho que, hasta que no se demuestre lo contrario, se puede concordar en singular y en plural. También sabemos que todo depende del núcleo, pues él te dará la clave. Ahora, un último secreto: fíjate bien en quién acompaña al núcleo. El sustantivo que encabece la estructura será decisivo para una buena concordancia.

Así pues en cuestión de género, las personas serían femenino. En cuanto al número puede darse la concordancia en singular o plural cuando es Un millón de personas

> Sin embargo, si el nombre cuantifivativo va acompañado de los artículos un/una, podrá alternar la concordancia de singular y plural

Espero te sirva como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

La clave para saber a quién se va a aplicar el sentido del verbo es el **sustantivo** de la oración (en tu ejemplo "personas", sustantivo femenino). En la frase: "Un millón de personas", el sujeto es "personas" mientras que "Un millón" (o "Dos millones", "Cinco", etc.) es un *adjetivo cardinal* aplicado al sujeto.

De ahí podemos deducir que lo correcto sería "Dos millones de personas están expuestas..." y "Un millón de personas tendrán...".

Comment: Bienvenido/a al sitio. Mira mis comentarios bajo la pregunta sobre lo que hemos encontrado sobre "un milione" en italiano: estoy (casi) convencida de que también es válido para "un millón" en español.